# QtGui.QFileDialog.getExistingDirectory() window won't close after directory has been chosen (PyQt)

Tags: python, ubuntu, pyqt, qfiledialog

I am trying to get a path with the `QtGui.QFileDialog.getExistingDirectory()` dialog window in a `python` program to ease things up for users while the rest of the program is in console output.
I have this piece of code for this purpose:

```
import sys, os
from PyQt4 import QtGui

def getpath(filename,
            noPathFileMsg='',
            wrongFolderMsg='',
            selectFolderMsg=''):

    try:
        f = open('./'+filename,'r')
    except IOError:
        folder = get_new_path(filename,
                                     noPathFileMsg, 
                                     selectFolderMsg)
    else:
        folder = f.readline()
        f.close()
        currentDir = os.getcwd()
        try:
            os.chdir(folder)
        except:
            folder = get_new_path(filename,
                                         wrongFolderMsg,
                                         selectFolderMsg)
        else:
            os.chdir(currentDir)
    finally:
        return folder

def get_new_path(filename,
                 infoMsg,
                 selectFolderMsg):

    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    QtGui.QMessageBox.about(None, 'No folder', infoMsg)
    folder = QtGui.QFileDialog.getExistingDirectory(None, selectFolderMsg)
    app.exit()
    if os.name == 'posix':
        folder += '/'
    elif os.name == 'nt':
        folder += '\\'
    g = open('./'+filename,'w')
    g.write(folder)
    g.close()
    return folder
if __name__ == '__main__':
    folderPath = getpath('pathtofolder.txt',
                         noPathFileMsg='The path to the folder has not been set',
                         wrongFolderMsg='The path folder saved cannot be reached',
                         selectFolderMsg='Please select a folder')
    print folderPath
    var = input('The program stopped at the input instruction, the dialog window should now be closed!')
```

If I call the getpath function the dialog window stays open until the script that called the function ends instead of closing just after this instruction:

```
folder = QtGui.QFileDialog.getExistingDirectory(None, selectFolderMsg)
```

If you run this code it will create a file that saves the directory saved with the dialog window in the folder where the script is run.

What did I do wrong?

By the way, I am on Ubuntu 12.04.
Thank you!
Cheers

Comment: I cannot reproduce the problem you describe using the code you've posted (testing on Linux).

Comment: I added a __main__ statement with some code so that the error seams more obvious. The Window should be closed when the program stops for input from the command line.

Comment: It's not obvious at all. Sequence of events for me: 1. run script. 2. message box appears ("the path to the folder has not been set"). 3. file dialog appears. 4. select folder, click ok. 5. file dialog closes. 6. console prints the selected folder and input instruction.

Comment: Ok then there is an issue with my system! Because when the program stops for input instruction the dialog window is still open for me. I have the same problem with two different computers but both on Ubuntu 12.04...

Comment: So what you're saying is that when you click 'OK' in the dialog box, it doesn't close? Or is it that the dialog is modeless, and so the `get_new_path` function returns before getting the `folder`?

Comment: First case: the dialog box does not close after clicking the OK button. It closes only after the whole script is over, in the meanwhile its just dead and does not respond. But apart from that everything works fine, the `get_new_path` function returns the right folder.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After setting up Ubuntu 12.04 in a VM, I can confirm that the dialog doesn't close properly after clicking "Open".

The problem seems to be caused by attempting to quit the `QApplication` inside the `get_new_path` function.

Instead, you should create a single, global `QApplication` object, and only quit it when the script completes:

```
def get_new_path(filename, infoMsg, selectFolderMsg):

    QtGui.QMessageBox.about(None, 'No folder', infoMsg)
    folder = QtGui.QFileDialog.getExistingDirectory(None, selectFolderMsg)
    ...

if __name__ == '__main__':

    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)

    folderPath = getpath(...)

    app.exit()
```